# Python iterate thru nested dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a question similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620168/looping-thru-a-nested-dictionary-in-python) to loop thru nested dictionaries..

I have a dictionary:

```
vavs = {'vav_1': {'network': '10:44', 'obj': '91044'},
        'vav_2': {'network': '10:45', 'obj': '91045'},
        'vav_3': {'network': '10:46', 'obj': '91046'},
        'vav_4': {'network': '10:47', 'obj': '91047'},
        'vav_5': {'network': '10:48', 'obj': '91048'},
        'vav_6': {'network': '10:49', 'obj': '91049'},
        'vav_7': {'network': '10:50', 'obj': '91050'}}
```

Is it possible to create a loop to extract the values of a `network` and `obj` on each loop iteration?

I can print `vavs['vav_1']['network']` and `vavs['vav_1']['obj']` manually but I am hoping to loop thru `vav_1` thru `vav_7` in an infinite fashion (loop doesn't end)

Comment: Can you be precise on *"infinite fashion (loop doesn't end)"*?

Comment: Well just to keep looping over and over.. 1 thru 7 then 1 thru 7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what expected output you're looking for, but if you just need to get the values, and you know that those two keys will be there every time, you could do something like:

```
for key, vav in vavs.items():
    network = vav['network']
    # do a thing with network, I guess?
    obj = vav['obj']
    # do a thing with obj, I guess?
```

Comment: This will not necessarily preserve the order of the items `vav_1` through `vav_7`.

Comment: he didn't say he cared about order /shrug

Comment: if order DOES matter the best solution would be to make vavs an OrderedDict in the first place

Answer (score 1):

- This will print values for each object.
- You can ignore value of k if not required by application.

```
for k, v in vavs.items():
    print(k, v['network'], v['obj'])
```

Or alternative

```
values = [x.values() for x in vavs.values()]
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you mean for:

> loop thru vav_1 thru vav_7 in an infinite fashion (loop doesn't end)

The following code print network and obj values infinite times:

```
while True:
    for k, v in vavs.items():
        print("{} {} {}".format(k, v['network'], v['obj']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (checkout the python docs for `dict.items()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)):

```
for k, v in vavs.items():
    print(v['network'], v['obj'])
```

The `dict.items()` (or `vavs.items()`  method in this case) creates a list of tuples where each item in the tuple is a key-value pair. Iterating over this list allows you to access each key-value pair in the dictionary.

Comment: You are already getting inside dictionary with `items`. No need to index again with `k`. You can just use `v`. And you want to use indexing using `k` you can use `vavs.keys`.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/):

```
In [155]: import pandas as pd

In [156]: vavs = {'vav_1': {'network': '10:44', 'obj': '91044'},^M
     ...:         'vav_2': {'network': '10:45', 'obj': '91045'},^M
     ...:         'vav_3': {'network': '10:46', 'obj': '91046'},^M
     ...:         'vav_4': {'network': '10:47', 'obj': '91047'},^M
     ...:         'vav_5': {'network': '10:48', 'obj': '91048'},^M
     ...:         'vav_6': {'network': '10:49', 'obj': '91049'},^M
     ...:         'vav_7': {'network': '10:50', 'obj': '91050'}}

In [157]: vdf = pd.DataFrame(vavs)

In [158]: vdf
Out[158]:
         vav_1  vav_2  vav_3  vav_4  vav_5  vav_6  vav_7
network  10:44  10:45  10:46  10:47  10:48  10:49  10:50
obj      91044  91045  91046  91047  91048  91049  91050

In [168]: x=0

In [169]: while x<1:
     ...:     for c in vdf.columns:
     ...:         print c, vdf.loc['network'][c], vdf.loc['obj'][c]
     ...:     x +=1
     ...:
vav_1 10:44 91044
vav_2 10:45 91045
vav_3 10:46 91046
vav_4 10:47 91047
vav_5 10:48 91048
vav_6 10:49 91049
vav_7 10:50 91050
```

Update `x=0` to as many iterations as you want, and if you want to do something fancy with the network/obj pairs, pandas may have simple and fast way to do it.